# How store entered data on scrolling in a uitableview that used as a small table for showing input elements?

Tags: ios, swift

I know about reusing cells in a `uitableview`. I have a `uitableview` with few cells(less that 10) that have some input elements(often textbox) on each cell. I want to use this `uitableview` just for showing input elements. But I know when scrolling happened cells data can't be exist. So I want a good and fast way for keeping cells data. Maybe use an array to keep data or if possible prevent cells from removing or other solutions.

**UPDATE**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, MyCustomCellDelegator 
{

fileprivate var cell:myTableViewCell!

@IBOutlet weak var mytbl: UITableView!

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    mytbl.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    mytbl.estimatedRowHeight = 44
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(_ tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // I created one section for each person. Each section has textboxes like name,family,etc.
    if (searchInputParam != nil) {
        return (searchInputParam!.Type1Count!.intValue + searchInputParam!.Type2Count!.intValue + searchInputParam!.Type3Count!.intValue)
    }
    else{
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if cell == nil {
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myTableViewCell") as! myTableViewCell
    }        
    cell.delegate = self
    if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section + 1 <= searchInputParam!.Type1Count!.intValue)
    {
        cell.lblType.text = "Type1"
    }
    else if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section + 1  <=  searchInputParam!.Type1Count!.intValue + searchInputParam!.Type2Count!.intValue)
    {
        cell.lblType.text = "Type2"
    }else if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).section + 1  <=  searchInputParam!.Type1Count!.intValue + searchInputParam!.Type2Count!.intValue + searchInputParam!.Type3Count!.intValue)
    {
        cell.lblType.text = "Type3"
    }
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate? I would assume that you already have a data source array -probably-, and you should let the cells to be filled based the data source array... what's the issue?

Comment: I know about your solution that you talked about. But if possible I don't want to use an array. Because If I use an array when can I store textbox values inside array?

Comment: Then declaring variables to set the desired values in the UITableViewCell would be good -somehow- to achieve what are you looking for...

Comment: create a array of size having number of textfields and add data in end editing of text and add them in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a relatively small amount of cells (as in your case `n < 10`), do not use reusing and dequeueing. The whole point of reusing is to prevent creation (and retaining) of large amount of cells. Moreover, if most of your cells are not of the same type (it seems to me that that's your case too), then reusing might become even less effective then not reusing the cells.

So in your particular case (`n < 10`, different cell types) - just create cells directly in the code as properties of the table view controller, e.g.:

```
import UIKit

class Table: UITableViewController {

    fileprivate let nameInputCell = NameInputCell()
    fileprivate let surnameInputCell = SurnameInputCell()
    fileprivate let phoneInputCell = PhoneInputCell()
    // ...

    ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            return nameInputCell
        case 1:
            return surnameInputCell
        case 2:
            return phoneInputCell

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The cell will hold its state across scrolling, so no problem for you.

**UPDATE FOR STORYBOARD PROTOTYPE CELLS**

Since you use storyboards, you will have to use a different approach to create instances of the cells (all the rest is the same):

```
import UIKit

class Table: UITableViewController {
    // use an optional
    fileprivate var nameInputCell: NameInputCell!
    fileprivate var surnameInputCell: SurnameInputCell!
    fileprivate var phoneInputCell: PhoneInputCell!
    // etc.

    ...

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            if nameInputCell == nil {
                // if not initialized yet, load the prototype from storyboard
                nameInputCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your identifier here") as! NameInputCell
            }
            return nameInputCell
        case 1:
            if surnameInputCell == nil {
                // if not initialized yet, load the prototype from storyboard
                surnameInputCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "your identifier here") as! SurnameInputCell
            }
            return surnameInputCell
            // etc.

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Just for reference, if you were having a big table with the repeating cell types, reusing would become very useful. In that case you would have to do the same thing as with all the other tableViews - create a data model, that would be used to hold data of the inputs - e.g. in case of textFields a dictionary  of strings:

```
fileprivate let dataModel: [IndexPath: String] = [:]
```

Then when providing a cell in `cellForRowAt`, you would configure it with the data:

```
if let input = dataModel[indexPath] {
    cell.textField.text = input
} else {
    cell.textField.text = ""
}
```

The last thing what you had to do would be to set up a delegate pattern from cells to tableViewController, to pass the changed data from the cell to the model:

```
protocol TextViewCellDelegate: class {
    func updateText(_ textViewCell: TextViewCell, newText: String)
}

class TextViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {
    weak var delegate: TextViewCellDelegate?

    ...

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        delegate?.updateText(self, newText: textField.text ?? "")
    }
}
```

In the tableViewController you would setup `self` as a delegate for each cell and in `updateText` you would just set the data back to the model.

Comment: I tried the first solution. I have a problem. As you know I defined my input elements inside 'nameInputCell' class. When I used cell reusing I could get them inside 'cellForRowAtIndexPath'. But now I try to get my input elements for example 'nameInputCell.txtPassengerName' inside 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' and all input elements are nil. What is the problem?

Comment: @MohammadEslami are you using storyboards?

Comment: @MohammadEslami if yes, check my updated section `UPDATE FOR STORYBOARD PROTOTYPE CELLS`

Comment: Yes, I put input elements in storyboard and connected them to their definition inside swift class file.

Comment: Excuse me, now another problem was occured. only the last section showed, for example if I have 3 sections, just the third section showed.(Although I think it's not important to the goal of question but I'm using Dynamic Prototypes Content and Grouped Style in my tableview and each section has one row)

Comment: @MohammadEslami Well, that the question on how you manage your table view controller.. without seeing its code it's impossible to help you

Comment: @MohammadEslami man.. you have to have 1 cell per row, that means if your table is supposed to have 10 rows, you need 10 cells.. in my example I have showed one cell as an example for name, but that was just an example

Comment: @MohammadEslami I have updated the answer.. Although I recommend to refactor out the code configuring the cells so that the `cellForRowAt` is as simple as possible

Comment: @MohammadEslami how does it look?